# SSO setup using Kerberos on windows server

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, kerberos, ntlm

I am new to SSO, We had a application using java implementation of kerberos SSO. Now we need to migrate the application to some other machine. I need to know what changes will be required in:
1. Service account in Active directory used for authentication.
2. Keytab files
3. Can the same AD principle name be used or a new one will be required.

Please assist with appropriate steps which are needed to be followed.
Appreciate your help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use service account in AD then I would expect not big changes:

- DNS record for this service
- Moving keytab to the new server

If machine account is in use then you would need:

- Reconfigure DNS
- Remove SPN from the current machine account
- Generate keytab for a new machine

Comment: Thanks giner.......I think keytab is also not mandatory for windows server 2008 r2?  I got it to work without keytab file.

Comment: Without keytab your server can't be sure that the Kerberos server is not forged. I'm not sure about your Kerberos implementation but MIT kerberos has an option "verify_ap_req_nofail" which if set true forces kerberos client to check the server.